# Using value set inside mysql query from outside the query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm using the mysql module and am doing multiple queries into my Mysql database. I'm getting an error in my NodeJS code where the variable "updateQuery" is undefined, even though I set it inside the first query. I thought that since this is synchronous (one query getting executed after the previous finishes) that the variable would be set. I do not want to nest the 2nd query inside the 1st query because I want this to be synchronous.

Is there any way to access the variables that are set inside the first query from outside that query??

Here's the code, given that I'm connected to the database already:

```
var result;
var updateQuery;


for (var i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {

    connect.query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = " + i, function(err, result) {

        result = result[0];
        updateQuery = "UPDATE table2 SET column1 = " + result;
    });

    connect.query(updateQuery, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });


}
```